# GraalVM native image: manual data source configuration fails with "not a managed typ"

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, native, graalvm

**`Spring Boot 3.2.0 / GraalVM 21`**

I'm migrating a complex spring boot application from Java 17 to GraalVM 21 native. To avoid hunting mysterious errors caused by the complexity, I've started by creating a simple spring boot app and populating it one by one. Currently, I'm stuck with a database issue. At first, I've set up spring data JPA with the following properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/graal
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

This works perfectly fine, as a traditional spring boot jar file as well as with a native image (after compiling with `mvn -Pnative compile: native`).

Since I am required to use two data sources at the same time, I have to create manual data source configurations. Hence, I've set up the above database settings like the following:

```java
@Configuration
@EntityScan({"com.example.database.entity"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "graalEMF",
        basePackages = { "com.example.database.entity" }
)
public class GraalDbConfig {
    @Bean("dataSource")
    @Primary
    DataSource graalDataSource() {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/graal");
        hikariConfig.setUsername("postgres");
        hikariConfig.setPassword("postgres");
        hikariConfig.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig);
    }

    @Bean("graalEMF")
    @Primary
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean graalEMF(@Qualifier("dataSource")DataSource dataSource,
                                                    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages(MyData.class).build();
    }

    @Bean("graalPMT")
    PersistenceManagedTypes graalPMT(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        return new PersistenceManagedTypesScanner(resourceLoader)
                .scan("com.example.database.entity");
    }
}
```

This works when running from a jar file. However, after compiling it into a native binary, running it fails with the error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'databaseApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository': Error creating bean with name 'myDataRepository': Not a managed type: class com.example.database.entity.MyData
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveValue(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:194) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolveObject(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:154) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.aot.AutowiredFieldValueResolver.resolve(AutowiredFieldValueResolver.java:143) ~[na:na]
```

I've tried the same with Tomcat datasource instead of Hikari with the same result. So it looks like I'm missing something here. I've tried to hint out with `@RegisterReflectionForBinding({MyData.class})` but that didn't help either.

Any idea how to get this running?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out, that PersistenceManagedTypes was missing. I've created a working example which shows how to use multiple datasource with custom configuration in a native spring-boot app:

https://github.com/DigitalMediageek/aot-database-issue